# Salesforce, Email Template, Field "Additional To" cuts the rest of address after "&" sign

Tags: javascript, email-template

Hi stackexchange community.

I have noticed that the e-mail template i've been using somehow cuts the rest of the address in **"Additional To"** field, if it contains **"&"** sign (e.g. test&test@gmail.com will look like "test" in the template).

I have a field in my Account page, which is the email address, and this is the javascript code for the button:

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js")} 

var account = new sforce.SObject("Account"); 

account.id = "{!Account.Id}"; 

if ("{!Account.Obj1__c}" == "Yes") 
{ 
window.open('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Account.Id}&p3_lkid={!Account.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}}&p24={!Account.Obj1_Email__c}&retURL={!Account.Id}&template_id=00XD0000001dNl9','Popup','height=800,width=800,left=100,top=100,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no'); 
} 
else 
{ 
window.open('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Account.Id}&p3_lkid={!Account.Id}&rtype=003&p2_lkid={!Case.ContactId}}&p24={!Account.Obj2_Email__c}&retURL={!Account.Id}&template_id=00XD0000001vGzq','Popup','height=800,width=800,left=100,top=100,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no'); 
} 

sforce.connection.update([account]);
```

I'd really appreciate if you could advise me how to deal with this issue.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb and assume the custom field you are talking about is `Account.Obj1_email__c` and `Account.Obj2_email__c`, and the input for your form is `...&p24={!Account.Obj2_Email__c}&retURL...`

When building a URL, there are several reserved characters for different purposes. the `&` character is a [parameter deliminator](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).

Because you are not escaping the `&` in the email address, it is assigning what comes before it to `p24` and then creating a new parameter with what ever comes after.

I think you simply need to [URLENCODE()](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) the email address, and you will see what you are expecting

Comment: Hi Tezyn! Thank you for your answer! Your assumption re field names is correct. Also, the e-mail field is based on customers name, so it's not a direct input, but a formula, like `IF(Current_Customer__r.Name = "Test", "test&test@gmail.com",`. Re your suggestion, i'm not really sure how can i do that. Shall i update the e-mail field formula to `IF(Current_Customer__r.Name = "Test", URLENCODE("test&test@gmail.com"),`? Or do i need to update `&p24={!Account.Obj2_Email__c}` to `&p24=URLENCODE({!Account.Obj2_Email__c})`. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: &p24={!URLENCODE(Account.Obj2_Email__c)}  Be sure to also change the reference to Account.Obj1_Email__c in the lines above.

Comment: Hi Tezyn, it worked like a charm! Thank you so much for helping me out!